# Multiple representations of the same entity in Oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables, the first one is `TB_RECIPE_DATA`, where the PK is the `ID_RECIPE` field. The second table is `TB_RECIPE_ITEM`, where the PK is composed of three fields: `ID_RECIPE`, `CD_LOT` and `CD_PRODUCT`. These two tables are related so that a recipe can have multiple items. The problem I'm facing is that when I try to register a recipe with more than one item, I get an error message "`InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple representations of the same entity`". When I register a recipe with just one item, it works.

In the research I've done, many indicate that it's because of *Cascade*, I've already tried switching to `cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}` and it didn't work. The mapping of the tables was done this way:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_RECIPE_DATA", schema = "A_SAMPLE")
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_RECIPE")
    private Long id;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<RecipeItem> items;
}



@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_RECIPE_ITEM", schema = "A_SAMPLE")
public class RecipeItem {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_RECIPE")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "CD_LOT")
    private String lot;
    
    @Column(name = "CD_PRODUCT")
    private Long code;
    
    @Column(name = "QT_PURCHASE")
    private Long purchaseQuantity;

    @Column(name = "FL_AVAILABLE")
    private Boolean available;
}
```

Comment: mappedBy = "id" isn't allowed and you must be missing a bunch of warnings/errors when these entities get loaded and processed regarding it. This is used to indicate a bidirectional mapping, and must point at a mapping in the target entity (RecipeItem) that maps back to this entity (Recipe) of that name. ID though is a basic Long mapping.  This is causing multiple RecipeItems to get assigned the same ID value, as it is being used somehow as the foreign key back to Recipe. I'd suggest something is wrong in Hibernate to allow this without throwing errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was happening because when changing, for example, recipe *A* with its respective items, each item has recipe *A* as part of the Primary Key, so I would be changing the recipe twice. The solution would be to work the bi-direction for this case. I will share my solution in case anyone experiences a similar problem.

Main class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_RECIPE_DATA", schema = "A_SAMPLE")
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_RECIPE")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<RecipeItem> items;
}
```

Child class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_RECIPE_ITEM", schema = "A_SAMPLE")
public class RecipeItem {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private RecipeItemPk id;
    
    @Column(name = "QT_PURCHASE")
    private Long purchaseQuantity;

    @Column(name = "FL_AVAILABLE")
    private Boolean available;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_RECIPE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Recipe recipe;
}
```

Primary Key class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "id", "lot", "code" })
@Embeddable
public class RecipeItemPk {

    @Column(name = "ID_RECIPE")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CD_LOT")
    private String lot;
    
    @Column(name = "CD_PRODUCT")
    private Long code;
}
```